# Async:False not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am using `async:false`. Therefore in case of `success` function, it should wait till it gets a response from the function and should stop executing the code that follows the `success` function.

However it executes the code following it. Shouldn't `async` lock the process? Now in mycase, I am making  `$('#val1loading').text('loading')` which has to keep showing loading until it gets a success from the ajax call. But it doesn't.

```
$("#val").change(function() {
$('#val1loading').text('loading');

if ($('#val').val() != '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Functions.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            async: false,
            'link': $('#val').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#val1").val(result[0]);

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $("#val1").val('');

        }
    });
} else {
    //some code
}
$('#val1loading').text('');
```

});

Comment: You can place the `$('#val1loading').text('');` inside success right

Comment: isn't `async: false,` supposed to be outside of the `data` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async is deprecated.Inorder to solve your problem use $('#val1loading').text('') in all the cases.

```
$("#val").change(function(){
$('#val1loading').text('loading');

if($('#val').val() != '') {
    $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxFunctions.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'update': 'parser','link': $('#val').val()},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#val1loading').text('');

                $("#val1").val(result[0]);


            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                $("#val1").val('');
                $('#val1loading').text('');


}
        });
    }else
{
    //some code
}
//$('#val1loading').text('');
```

Comment: `async: false` is _not_ deprecated - however you can't mix it with Promises / Deferred.  It's still a bad idea, though.

Comment: @Alnitak As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().So I have written.

Comment: and 1.  not removed `async: false` from the `data` object, 2.  repeated chunks of code that should have gone into a `complete:` handler (which is called regardless of success or error)

Answer (score 2):

The `async: false` should be in the main object passed to `$.ajax`, not contained within the `data` sub-object.

That said, using synchronous AJAX is almost always a bad idea precisely because it does "lock the process" as you mentioned in the question.

Get used to writing properly async code, where every action in the program happens via callbacks as a result of events (e.g. AJAX completion) or better yet use "Promises", e.g.:

```
$('#val').on('change', function() {
    var $val1 = $('#val1');
    var $loading = $('#val1loading');
    var val = this.value.trim();

    if (val.length > 0) {
        $loading.text('loading');
        $.ajax({
            url: "Functions.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { link: val },
        }).then(function(result) {
            $val1.val(result[0]);
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            $val1.val('');
        }).always(function() {
            $loading.text('');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So could u suggest a solution?

Comment: @RamMalhotra I did, for your immediate problem.  If you want to use async properly, there's _thousands_ of other questions already here relating to that.

Answer (score 0):

i think dont use async false like this.
change it to :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "Functions.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'link': $('#val').val()},
        async:false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#val1").val(result[0]);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $("#val1").val('');
         }
    });
```